# Select reoccuring fields in database

Tags: mysql

I'm very new to mySQL first and foremost so I'm not sure if what I'm trying is possible. I have 2 questions on my website, for which the answers are injected as an id (First Question: yes=1, no=2; Second Question: yes=3, no=4) into a column called pollOptionId. I can find out people who have said yes to each question, but can't figure out how to find out people who have answered yes to the first question and, say, yes to the second question.

Doing a

```
select * from poll_question
where pollOptionId = 1
or pollOptionId = 3
```

shows all that have answered both questions, what I want is to find out those that have said 1 and 3. I can manually check, as I have a memberId column on the table so for example people that have said both have I can tell as there memberId is shown twice!

So really what I want is

```
select * from poll_question
where pollOptionId = 1
or pollOptionId = 3
WHERE THE MEMBERID OCCURS TWICE
```

obviously the last line is not correct syntax but helps demonstrate what I want!

Really hope that all made sense! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

you want a having clause.. group by whatever the user's data is.. aka username user_id whatever that is.. and then say when there are exactly two records matching after grouped will be when they have pollOptionId of 1 and 3

```
SELECT * 
FROM poll_question
WHERE pollOptionId = 1
   OR pollOptionId = 3
GROUP BY memberid
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

another possible way to do this is like so..

```
SELECT * 
FROM poll_question
WHERE pollOptionId = 1
  AND memberid IN(SELECT memberid FROM poll_question WHERE pollOptionId = 3)
```